# The page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, tomcat, http, java

I have deploy my web app to EC2(AWS) instance.
Firewall, tomcat configuration etc are OK.

When i try acess to it via browser i see such error.
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/34yjbbqkfi0zzvj/aws.png)

I see this in all browsers. Can you help me?

Cache was cleaned too.

Comment: Hard to tell without more info. Are you using `response.sendRedirect()` in your java code? Is Tomcat fronted by a Web server or reverse proxy (e.g. Apache)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS loadbalancer issue. So all ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code or server config is redirecting in a loop.

That's all we can tell you without code. Examine both and make sure you're redirecting appropriately.

Comment: AWS loadbalancer issue :(